# Representing space of non-representable sheaf

Tags: category-theory

In Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture21.pdf) Example 21.30 he discusses an example to use representing space to represent a non-representable sheaf.  The goal is to show $\mathcal{F}(M) = \text{Map}(M,\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H})$ which shows $\mathcal{F}$ is representable by $\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}$.  He uses the phase "in essence $\mathcal{F}(M)$ is the space of smooth maps $M \to \mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}$".  I don't quite get the reasoning behind his "in essence".  Could somebody please help?  For your convenience I reproduce the example below

[image]